# JAVA_HOME not updating in Environment Variables? (Windows 10)

Tags: java, windows, environment-variables

When I update my JAVA_HOME System variable to the v11 jdk, the %JAVA_HOME% in the User Path Variable doesn't update.

[Environment Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cy8t2.png)

As you can see in the image, the JAVA_HOME is set to v11 while the Path User variable is still set to v8. Any ideas?

I should mention that I have v8 and v11 JDKs successfully installed on my computer. I've tried saving and reopening the Environment variables window and restarting the computer.

Comment: Sorry, your solution didn't work. Also, are you referring to the Path System variable? Not sure what you mean by User Path System variable

Comment: let me check, I will fix it

Answer (score 0):

in Windows, user variables will override system variables.
to solve your problem, just remove the path of Java in user variables simply.
or, you can set the same value of path for Java 11 in user variables.

Comment: While this is correct and occasionally useful to know, the screenshot shows that there's no name conflict. They are using the system variable in the user's PATH.

Comment: when you compile java files using ```javac```, it should be found from the ```path``` variable. that's why you must modify the path from jdk8 to JDK 11 for your user variables. ```JAVA_HOME``` means where to find the classes from JDK to compile. for example, ```import java.util.ArrayList;```, the compiler knows where to find the class  ```ArrayList```. They are different.

Answer (score 0):

The system variables are re-applied to the user's Path when you  press `OK` on the System Properties dialog (the one immediately before your Environment Variables dialog). It should reflect the updated value when you re-open it.

[image]

Comment: Do not post comments as answers.

Comment: This is not a comment, I reproduced the issue on my machine exactly as shown in the screenshot. It goes away when the user presses Ok on this dialog. I changed the wording to not make it a question/comment.

Comment: Well ... you edited your post. At first, it was a question without any screenshot. ;-)

Comment: The screenshot didn't add anything that was not already in the answer text, but I agree I shouldn't have worded it as a comment.

Comment: Sorry, I've done this a few times, however clicking ok in the System properties dialog did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Open Environment Variables.
2. Edit the User Path Variable in the System Variables section.
3. Find the path corresponding to the v8 JDK.
4. Edit that path to the v11 JDK path.
5. Save changes and close the Environment Variables window.
6. User Path Variable should now use the v11 JDK.

Comment: Sorry, this did not work for me

Comment: @PleasePleasePleaseHelp let me check, I will fix it

Answer (score -1):

I have encountered this now but I couldn't find the answer here so I am sharing it.

I updated my environment variables but it does not show on cmd when I try java -version it still shows java 8. I fixed it by:

1. Java control panel -> java -> view -> users (I added my updated jdk and enabled, apply changes) Reference: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/update_runtime_settings.html
2. copy the java.exe and javaw.exe from your jdk/bin to Oracle\Java\javapath (override it the existing were from your old version)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).